# Flutter: do not redirect after authenticating

Tags: flutter

I'm doing a simple check in Flutter, where after authenticating, it should redirect to HomePage().

I debugged and after authentication authController.isAuth = true but it doesn't refer to HomePage().

```
class AuthOrHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthOrHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthController authController = Provider.of(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: authController.tryAutoLogin(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('Ocorreu um erro!'),
          );
        } else {
          if (authController.isAuth) {
            return const HomePage();
          } else {
            return const InitPage();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Hello Rafael, and welcome. Could you edit your question and add the code to ```authController.tryAutoLogin()```? Also, do you really mean ```redirecting``` in this case? Or just showing the correct page? I believe there are many ways to solve your problem, It's just that adding these infos will make it easier to whoever answer your question. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthOrHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthOrHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthController authController = Provider.of(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: authController.tryAutoLogin(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('Ocorreu um erro!'),
          );
        } else {
          if (authController.isAuth) {
            // Navigate to the HomePage
            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
              );
            });
          } else {
            return const InitPage();
          }
        }
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, if you want to navigate from one screen to another you can use `Navigator`.

```
class AuthOrHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthOrHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthController authController = Provider.of(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: authController.tryAutoLogin(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('Ocorreu um erro!'),
          );
        } else {
          if (authController.isAuth) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const HomePage()));
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const InitPage()));
          }
          return SizedBox();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

For more : [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#:~:text=In%20Flutter%20these%20elements%20are,pop.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#:%7E:text=In%20Flutter%20these%20elements%20are,pop.)

Comment: Thank you, but it turns out that inside a FutureBuilder it asks to leave the builder as async, and thus it presents several errors.

Comment: I believe this answer is not correct or at least not complete. This happens inside a builder function and therefore this function has to return a widget.